# Joining Multiple Tables And Merging Data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, concatenation

I have four tables I want to join together, but one table I want to group_concat two specific records.

```
Product_to_category PC
P_ID C_ID
1     1
2     2
2     3
1     3


Product P
P_ID P_PRICE
1    12
2    3
3    4

Product_Description PD
P_ID  Language_id   PD_Name
1       1           Chips
1       2           Chips (In a different language)
2       1           Soda
2       2           Soda (In a different language)

Category Description CD
C_ID   Language_id  CD_Name
1      1            Junk Food
1      2            Junk Food (In a different language)
2      1            Drinks
2      2            Drinks (In a different language)
3      1            Imported
3      2            Imported (In a different language)


Product_attribute PA
P_ID  A_ID  Language_ID  A_TEXT
1     1      1            Brand A
1     2      1            300g
1     3      1            Ketchup
1     1      2            Brand A
1     2      2            300g 
1     3      2            Ketchup (Different language)
2     1      1            Brand B
2     2      1            500mL
2     3      1            Cherry
2     1      2            Brand B
2     2      2            500mL
2     3      2            Cherry (Different language)
```

What I want to do is below:

```
P.P_ID |  P.P_PRICE | PD.LANGUAGE_ID | PD.PD_NAME | CD.C_ID | CD.CD_NAME | Attribute
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1    |  12        |   1            | Chips      |  1      | Junk Food | Brand A 300g
  1    |  12        |   2            | Chips      |  1      | Junk Food | Brand A 300g
  2    |  3         |   1            | Soda       |  2      | Drinks    | Brand B 500mL
  2    |  3         |   2            | Soda       |  2      | Drinks    | Brand B 500mL
  2    |  3         |   1            | Soda       |  3      | Imported  | Brand B 500mL
  2    |  3         |   2            | Soda       |  3      | Imported  | Brand B 500mL
  1    |  12        |   1            | Chips      |  3      | Imported  | Brand A 300g
  1    |  12        |   2            | Chips      |  3      | Imported  | Brand A 300g
```

Basically, I'm trying to load the Product with the Category and Attribute. It is working fine by just left joining the tables without the Product_attribute PA. I can't figure out how to put the attribute together. Below is my code:

```
select P.P_ID, P.P_PRICE, PD.LANGUAGE_ID, PD.PD_Name, CD.C_ID, CD.CD_NAME, 
(select group_concat(PA.A_TEXT) from PA where (PA.A_ID=1 or PA.A_ID=2) and PA.P_ID =
P.P_ID group by PA.P_ID) as attribute from PC left join PD on PC.P_ID = PD.P_ID
left join CD on PC.C_ID = CD.C_ID
left join P on P.P_ID = PC.P_ID
where PD.language_id = CD.language_id and (PD.language_id=1 or PD.language_id=2)
```

I apologize if this is a bit confusing

Updated 04/26/2013
Here a summary what goes through in the tables and what I want to accomplish: Product_to_category PC table links a product to their categories and a category to their products. A product could belong to multiple categories and a category could belong to multiple product. A product in P table has their product values like price, and its description is in product_description PD table. A product could have two rows of product description (bilingual). A product has attribute values as well in product_attribute PA table like brand ('Brand A', 'Brand B') and volume/weight ('300g', '500ml'). A product could belong to multiple categories, and a category could have multiple products. Each category has two descriptions (bilingual). What I want to accomplish to show each product with their multiple categories in the correct language, and concatenate the attribute text.

Please let me know if there needs further explanation.

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT should be in your main SELECT clause, not in a subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select P.P_ID, P.P_PRICE, PD.LANGUAGE_ID, PD.PD_Name, CD.C_ID, CD.CD_NAME, 
group_concat(DISTINCT PA.A_TEXT) as attribute
from PC left join PD on PC.P_ID = PD.P_ID
left join CD on PC.C_ID = CD.C_ID
left join P on P.P_ID = PC.P_ID
left join PA on PA.P_ID = P.P_ID AND (PA.A_ID=1 or PA.A_ID=2)
where PD.language_id = CD.language_id and (PD.language_id=1 or PD.language_id=2)
GROUP BY P.P_ID, PD.LANGUAGE_ID
```

[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8aa9a/6)

Comment: +1 - I was creating my own SQL fiddle and just when I was coming here to post the query you beat me to it.

Comment: Thanks dude! That was quick! I was struggling with it for hours!

Comment: Hey sorry, Barmar. The results are not what I anticipated. The number of records in PC have 6127 records. There would be 12,000+ records when I retrieve data by joining PC and CD together, and there would be 11,500+ records when I retrieve data by joining PC and CD. The reason it is more than the actual number of records is each CD and PD could have 2 languages. The query I pull only provide 1000+ records. Please let me know if I am not explaining it properly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No, you're not. What's the difference between the expected and actual results in the fiddle? I think the expected results in your question are wrong. For Chips in language 2, CD_NAME should be "Junk Food (in a different language)", not "Junk Food".

Comment: Basically, PC table has Product_ID (P_ID) and Category_ID (C_ID) for each record. A Product_ID could belong to multiple Category_ID. In my example, what I should have written is P_ID 2 could belong to C_ID 2 and also C_ID 3. When I use your query, it would not pull all the C_ID belonging to the P_ID.

Comment: Also, a Category_ID C_ID could belong to multiple Product_ID P_ID as well. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you just need to add C_ID to the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Or if you want to see all the categories in the same row of the result, use `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CD.CD_NAME)`.

Comment: You nailed it again, Barmar! Thanks!